# Sich erfreuen + Dativ?

Tags: dative

In einem Zeitungsartikel, lese ich:

> Hier im hohen Norden erfreuen sich die langen, attraktiven
>   Ostseestrände einer wachsenden Beliebheit.

Warum wird hier „Beliebheit“ im Dativ benutzt ?

Comment: Das ist Genitiv, kein Dativ.

Comment: @tofro Dem Dativ sein Feind :-D

Comment: Ich halte es für wenig sinnvoll, den wesentlichen Bestandteil der Frage durch edit unkenntlich zu machen. Deshalb rollback. Gefragt wurde (fälschlicherweise) nach Dativ und nicht nach Genitiv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Viele Verben im Deutschen regieren einen bestimmten Kasus - *sich jemandes/einer Sache erfreuen* fordert eben als eines der wenigen (und weniger werdenden) Verben den Genitiv.

Die Frage nach dem "warum" lässt sich über ein einfaches "das ist eben so" hinaus wohl schwer beantworten - Latein z.B. kennt einen *genitivus criminalis*, der sich ähnlich auch in der deutschen Sprache wiederfindet ("jemanden eines Verbrechens beschuldigen"). Im Mittelhochdeutschen waren Verben, die den Genitiv fordern, noch wesentlich verbreiteter. Im heutigen Deutsch hat sich deren Anzahl so stark verringert, dass man schon fast eine definitive [Liste](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Verben_mit_Genitiv) machen kann (es dürften, grob geschätzt, etwa 40 Verben sein, manche davon sind heute allerdings sehr ungebräuchlich).

Comment: Bei einigen Verben wird auch eine Präposition verwendet, hier "sich an einer Sache erfreuen", die dann den Fall bestimmt, hierbei immerhin beibehält. Wäre für die Frage relevant, welche Form ursprünglich ist? Einiges auf der Liste gilt nicht immer, sondern nur in bestimmten Idiomen. So ist "sich wachsender Beliebt erfreuen" nun eine stehende Wendung, in der "an" keinen Platz findet. Wieso eigentlich "einer", etwa auch "zweier"? Ohne Adjektiv und Artikel wird jedoch kein Schuh draus. Der Artikel ist nur nötig für den Reim auf einen Artikel in einem Relativsatz, "einer Beliebtheit, die ... ist".

Comment: @vectory: Die stehende Wendung erkenne ich nicht, *erfreut sich großer Nachfrage/ wachsenden Zuspruchs,* sind genau so gebildet. *Einer* ist hier ein unbestimmter Artikel, kein Zahlwort. Der Rest des Kommentars erschließt sich mir gar nicht, vielleicht solltest du ihn in eine etwas ausführlichere eigene Antwort umwandeln.

Comment: @vectory *sich **einer** Sache erfreuen* habe ich gewählt, damit man den Genitiv erkennt - *sich etwas erfreuen* hört sich erstens doof an und zweitens ist der Genitiv nicht mehr sichtbar.

Comment: @guidot das ist mir bewusst, danke für die Eingabe. Deine Beispiele gehören dennoch einem engen semantischen Feld an. Das soll "idiomatisch" im weitesten Sinne, in dem Fall.bedeuten. *ein-* ist zumeist auch ein Zahlwort, da unzählbare Objekte gewöhnlich keinen unbestimmten Artikel brauchen, bspw. "Ich habe _ Sand". Der Fall müsste gar nicht markiert werden, wenn das Verb eindeutig wäre, etwa wegen *er-* Die Bedeutung der Phrase ist scheinbar anders, wenn der Artikel fehlt, "sich beliebtheit erfreuen". Das wundert mich. "er-" kontrastiert mit reinem "freuen", klingt für mich nach Erzeugung o.ä.

Comment: @vectory das *er-* muss nicht sein: *sich seines Lebens freuen*

Comment: Steht nichtt auf jener Liste. Könnte eine Deduplication von "er er-freut sich seines Lebens" sein, besonders im Norddeutschen, wo *r* und *a* nah beisammen liegen, und *eaeafreuen* quasi nur wie ein langgezogenes *eafreuen* klingen kann (obwohl jedes *e* unterschiedlich lang ist, und die Betonung das auch sonst regeln könnte).

Comment: Genaugenommen würde ich statt *X erfreut sich einer wachsenden Beliebtheit* eher *X erfreut sich wachsender Beliebtheit* sagen.